# Cannot view context with being logged into manager

Tags: modx-revolution

**ISSUE**

I want my site to be in two languages, English and Spanish.    I have followed the excellent instructions from this [post](http://designfromwithin.com/blog-webdesign-development/2012/01/12/modx-multilingual-setting-up-babel-and-have-a-website-with-multible-languages/).

If I am logged into the manager in one tab and then open another tab to a spanish page I do see the spanish page.   For example,  http://www.site.com/es/somepage.html, works!

But, if I am not logged into the manager and try to navigate to this page I get a 503 error, page not found.   I don't see anything in the Error log.

Obviously, this is some security issue, but I have looked at the anonymous user and they do have load access to the spanish and english contexts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

When I duplicated the web context to make my Spanish context none of the resources under the Spanish context were published.  Arghhh.

Thanks for your help @Sean Kimball.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did not grant the anonymous user access to the Spanish context.

- that article looks to be several years old, check out the official babel website: http://www.multilingual-modx.com/ there is a step by step tutorial there as well.
- what version of modx? 2.2.6 is somewhat different when it comes to setting up contexts.
- what error did you get? a 503 [server error] or a 404 [page not found]?

Comment: Thanks for your response.    I am using 2.2.5.   I get a 503 error.   How do you grant the anonymous user access to the Spanish Context?  I have went to the Spanish Context-->Access Permissions and the 'Access Permissions' and the anonymouse user has 'Load Only'  just like the web Context.

Comment: let's see your gateway plugin, a 503 error could even be a php syntax error.